# gRPC file upload always returns The request stream was aborted

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-dotnet

Im trying to upload a file from the client to the server in chunks.  Is been ten years since I have tried to code a chunk uploader myself, this is harder then I remember.

## upload.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcService1";

package upload;

// The FileDownload service definition.
service Uploader {
  // Download a file
  rpc UploadFileStream(stream UploadFileRequest) returns (UploadFileResponse) {}
}

// The request message containing file data, and file name
message UploadFileRequest {
  bytes data = 1;
  string fileName = 2;
}

// The response from the upload containing the filePath
message UploadFileResponse {
  string filePath =1;
}
```

## UploaderService

```
using Grpc.Core;

namespace GrpcService1.Services;

public class UploaderService : Uploader.UploaderBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;

    public UploaderService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public override async Task<UploadFileResponse> UploadFileStream(IAsyncStreamReader<UploadFileRequest> request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        while (await request.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(request.Current.Data);
        }

        return new UploadFileResponse(){ FilePath = @"c:\uploaded\file1.txt"};
    }
}
```

## client upload test method

```
 public static async Task Upload(GrpcChannel channel, string filePath)
    {
        var clientUpFile = new Uploader.UploaderClient(channel);
        using var uploadStream = clientUpFile.UploadFileStream();

        var x = File.Exists(filePath);
        
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath) )
        {
            var bufferSize = 512000;
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            var lastBytesRead = 0;
            var byteCount = 0;

            while ((lastBytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lastBytesRead);
                
                if (lastBytesRead > 0)
                {
                    await uploadStream.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new UploadFileRequest()
                    {
                        Data = await ByteString.FromStreamAsync(fileStream, CancellationToken.None),
                        FileName = filePath
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

## Issue

The client seems to be uploading the chunks by look at its console. log

> Hello World
> [ { "name": "Files\DaimtoLogo.jpg" } ]
> 512

However the server seems to get a single chunk, which makes sense as there appears to be only one.  Then it throws an error reading the stream.

> Google.Protobuf.ByteString
> info: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler[14]
> Error reading message.
> System.IO.IOException: The request stream was aborted.
> ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException: The HTTP/2 connection faulted.
> ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoReceive()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.DuplexPipeStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
> at System.IO.Pipelines.StreamPipeReader.g__Core|36_0(StreamPipeReader reader, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ReadInputAsync()
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result) at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult() at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2MessageBody.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token) at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions.ReadStreamMessageAsync[T](PipeReader input, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Func`2 deserializer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> fail: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler[6]
> Error when executing service method 'UploadFileStream'.
> System.IO.IOException: The request stream was aborted.
> ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException: The HTTP/2 connection faulted.
> ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection.DoReceive()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.DuplexPipeStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token) at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
> at System.IO.Pipelines.StreamPipeReader.g__Core|36_0(StreamPipeReader reader, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ReadInputAsync()
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
> at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result) at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult() at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2MessageBody.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token) at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions.ReadStreamMessageAsync[T](PipeReader input, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Func`2 deserializer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.HttpContextStreamReader`1.<MoveNext>g__MoveNextAsync|9_0(ValueTask`1 readStreamTask)
> at GrpcService1.Services.UploaderService.UploadFileStream(IAsyncStreamReader`1 request, ServerCallContext context) in C:\Development\FreeLance\Glassix\gRCPTest\grcp-samaple\gRCPService\GrpcService1\Services\UploaderService.cs:line 16 at Grpc.Shared.Server.ClientStreamingServerMethodInvoker`3.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ServerCallContext serverCallContext, IAsyncStreamReader`1 requestStream) at Grpc.Shared.Server.ClientStreamingServerMethodInvoker`3.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ServerCallContext serverCallContext, IAsyncStreamReader`1 requestStream) at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.CallHandlers.ClientStreamingServerCallHandler`3.HandleCallAsyncCore(HttpContext httpContext, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext)
> at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.CallHandlers.ServerCallHandlerBase`3.<HandleCallAsync>g__AwaitHandleCall|8_0(HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Method`2 method, Task handleCall)

1. what is closing the stream
2. shouldnt the stream stay open until it gets the response back from the server that the file was uploaded?

Note: Updated to fix a few typos noted in answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the issue.  The key here is `await uploadStream.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();`

I found this single line in the documentation under [Client streaming call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

> When the client has finished sending messages, `RequestStream.CompleteAsync()` should be called to notify the service.

```
public static async Task Upload(GrpcChannel channel, string filePath)
    {
        var clientUpFile = new Uploader.UploaderClient(channel);
        using var uploadStream = clientUpFile.UploadFileStream();

        // check file exits before uploading 
        if (!File.Exists(filePath)) throw new FileNotFoundException();

        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath) )
        {
            var buffer =  ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(32 * 1024);
            var lastBytesRead = 0;

            while ((lastBytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                if (lastBytesRead > 0)
                {
                    await uploadStream.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new UploadFileRequest()
                    {
                        Data = ByteString.CopyFrom(buffer,0 , lastBytesRead),
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
                    });
                }
            }
            
            // Notify the service when the client has finished sending messages
            await uploadStream.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();  
            ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
        }

        // read the response
        var response = await uploadStream.ResponseAsync;
        Console.WriteLine(response.FilePath);
        
    }
```

## final UploaderService

for anyone that needs this in the future.  This will store the file thats been uploaded.

```
public class UploaderService : Uploader.UploaderBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;

    public UploaderService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task<UploadFileResponse> UploadFileStream(IAsyncStreamReader<UploadFileRequest> request,
        ServerCallContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var dir = "Files";
            var fileName = "temp";

            await using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite($"{dir}\\temp"))
            {
                await foreach (var chunkMsg in request.ReadAllAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    fileName = chunkMsg.FileName;

                    fs.Write(chunkMsg.Data.ToByteArray());
                }
            }

            System.IO.File.Move($"{dir}\\temp", $"{dir}\\{fileName}", true);

            _logger.LogDebug(@"[FileUploaded] 'Files\{FileName}' uploaded", fileName);
            return new UploadFileResponse() { FilePath = $@"Files\{fileName}" };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new UploadFileResponse() { ErrorMessage = e.Message };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: glad you found it!

Comment: Its not 100% working.  its not uploading any bytes yet but the bug in this question is fixed.

Comment: Well, the `FromStreamAsync` looks wrong; that would attempt to upload the entire stream each time, and if the stream is shorter than the buffer, you've probably *already drained it*; try one of the `ByteString` constructors / static helpers that take an array-segment / memory - perhaps `ByteString.CopyFrom(buffer, 0, lastBytesRead)`. Unfortunately this will involve a buffer copy. I could suggest ways to avoid that, but they'll require library-level changes (i.e. switching to alternative tools).

Comment: great minds think alike Data = ByteString.CopyFrom(buffer),    <--- is close but its giving me garbage at the end of the file.

Comment: @DalmTo yes, you're writing too many bytes - see the edit I made to the comment which shows the correct usage

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for your help. Thats an updated working version.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the missing `await` here:

```cs
uploadStream.RequestStream.WriteAsync(...);
```

is causing invalid overlapped writes, crashing the client code, causing the end of the `using` scope of `uploadStream`, destroying that conversation. The fact that you have `async void` and no exception handling means that you probably just aren't observing this failure in the client.

Suggestions:

1. add the `await`
2. never use `async void`

As a side note: you can probably lease your buffer here:

```cs
var buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(32 * 1024); // or whatever
// ...
while ((lastBytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{ ... }
// ...
ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
```

Comment: well spotted,  but it didn't change anything.  same error.  Typo's fixed in question.