# YARP forwarding to gRPC endpoint fails with 'Incomplete message' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, ms-yarp, duende

I am trying to expose one of my gRPC services (protobuf-net) more easily by using YARP to forward HTTP 1.1 calls to HTTP2.0 gRPC endpoints.

My main issue is that I am getting an error like this whenever I attempt to forward such a call.

```
2023-10-09 21:58:57 info: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler[14]
2023-10-09 21:58:57       Error reading message.
2023-10-09 21:58:57       Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Incomplete message.")
2023-10-09 21:58:57          at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions.ReadSingleMessageAsync[T](PipeReader input, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Func`2 deserializer)
2023-10-09 21:58:57 info: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler[7]
2023-10-09 21:58:57       Error status code 'Internal' with detail 'Incomplete message.' raised.
```

This is what I can see on the logs of my .NET 7 WebAPI that implements the gPRC service.

The BFF service (Duende.BFF), however is able to forward my call properly, or at least it looks like.

```
2023-10-09 21:58:57 [18:58:57 Information] Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder
2023-10-09 21:58:57 Proxying to http://host.docker.internal:64868/<redactedNamespace>.LocationGrpcService/GetLocations HTTP/2 RequestVersionExact no-streaming
```

This gRPC service does work whenever I do grpc-style calls to it, either from C# or from Postman, so the implementation of the service shouldn't be the issue.

```
  using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://host.docker.internal:64868");
  var locationService = channel.CreateGrpcService<ILocationGrpcService>();
  var locations = await locationService.GetLocationsAsync();
```

But, if I am doing my request from my Angular HttpClient then it will 'fail' with the upper error, while I am getting these response headers.

[image]

I have attempted to investigate with an interceptor what's going on by doing this:

```
   services.AddCodeFirstGrpc(config =>
   {
       config.ResponseCompressionLevel = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal;
       config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
       config.Interceptors.Add<ServerLoggerInterceptor>();
   });
```

The problem is, I can catch breakpoints only for my valid gRPC calls (postman, gRPC to gRPC, gRPC health-checks, etc) but not for my YARP call.

This is my interceptor code

```
 public class ServerLoggerInterceptor : Interceptor
 {
     private readonly ILogger<ServerLoggerInterceptor> _logger;

     public ServerLoggerInterceptor(ILogger<ServerLoggerInterceptor> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }

     public override async Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(
         TRequest request,
         ServerCallContext context,
         UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
     {
         //LogCall<TRequest, TResponse>(MethodType.Unary, context);

         try
         {
             return await continuation(request, context);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             // Note: The gRPC framework also logs exceptions thrown by handlers to .NET Core logging.
             _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error thrown by {context.Method}.");

             throw;
         }
     }
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html) I can see that my code is this one:

```
 **INTERNAL 13  Internal errors. This means that some invariants expected by the underlying system have been broken. This error code is reserved for serious errors.**
```

So since my gRPC implementation works, and only my YARP calls are failing, I can safely assume my YARP is somehow configured wrong, let me share it here.

```
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "video-provider": {
        "Transforms": [
          { "PathRemovePrefix": "/bff" }
        ],
        "ClusterId": "video-provider-rest",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/bff/video-provider/{**catch-all}"
        },
        "Metadata": {
          "Duende.Bff.Yarp.TokenType": "User",
          "Duende.Bff.Yarp.AntiforgeryCheck": "true"
        }
      },
      "video-provider-grpc": {
        "Transforms": [
          { "PathRemovePrefix": "/bff/grpc/video-provider" },
          {
            "RequestHeader": "content-type",
            "Set": "application/grpc"
          }
        ],
      
        "ClusterId": "video-provider-grpc",
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/bff/grpc/video-provider/{*any}"
        },
        "Metadata": {
          "Duende.Bff.Yarp.TokenType": "User",
          "Duende.Bff.Yarp.AntiforgeryCheck": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    "Clusters": {
      // This is used for proxying data to VP thru HTTP1.1
      "video-provider-rest": {
        "Destinations": {
          "video-provider/destination1": {
            "Address": "http://host.docker.internal:64869/"
          }
        }
      },
      // This can be used for proxying HTTP1.1 to HTTP2 calls
      "video-provider-grpc": {
        "HttpRequest": {
          "Version": "2",
          "VersionPolicy": "RequestVersionExact"
        },
        "Destinations": {
          "video-provider/destination1": {
            "Address": "http://host.docker.internal:64868"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I am setting the destination to use the HTTP 2.0 protocol, I do set up any additional stuff like explicitly setting the request header's content-type to be of type `application/grpc`  
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have checked out [Duende's BFF Yarp implementation](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/bff/apis/yarp/) and couldn't find anything of use.
I have also reviewed [MS's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0#calling-grpc-services-hosted-in-a-sub-directory) in regard to troubleshooting gRPC calls but it feels like I'm dancing around some sort of misconfiguration of YARP from my end.

Edit:
I'm running on .NET Core 7 WebAPI
Duende.BFF

I'm running on latest stable packages.

Comment: Are you using same version of GRPC in client as being used in Server?  See : https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/1778

Comment: I am not sure tbh because I'm just YARPing my way from my BFF microservice to my gRPC endpoint.
I've even installed the latest package of YARP.ReverseProxy - 2.0.1 (BFF.Duende.YARP has 2.0.0 package)  but still the same behavior.

Comment: The connection is completing and the error is occurring while the request is being processed.  The response header says the server is Kestrel.  I found following from Aug 24, 2022.  Some of the bugs may of been fixed with latest version.  It looks like  good start using Yarp and Kestrel.  I always check dates to see if they are still applicable : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/bringing-kestrel-and-yarp-to-azure-app-services/  Also https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/runtimes.html

Comment: You are getting "Error reading message" which also occurred here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74371714/grpc-file-upload-always-returns-the-request-stream-was-aborted  I also found additional troubleshooting method here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @jdweng I run the current dev env on my local, with docker compose, hence the docker.local.etc urls that I have posted in the config. I did go over the provided links, appreciate it, but the issue they're discussing is a 'service' one, where in my scenario the gRPC service works, but the YARP fails for no apparent reason.

Comment: You are making a HTTP connection from a client to a server. The server is failing.  It doesn't matter if the server is on a remote machine or a localhost.  The server is failing when reading the Message which is the body/content of the HTTP request.  The Yarp is running on server acting as a relay taking a HTTP 1.1 (stream mode) from client and forwarding the data to a HTTP 2.0.

Comment: did you turn on logging for Yarp?  https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/diagnosing-yarp-issues.html